# CS:GO Friends can't connect

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I made a server that runs from my laptop. I can connect to it myself via my desktop, but other players can not. Here is a pic from portforwards [image: PortForward]

(The IP is the laptops IPv4 address, as I'm running the server with the laptop over Wi-Fi.) I connect with my Public IP 86.50.xx.xxx, but yeah, the other players can't join. What should I try? I have tried to search the internet and follow guides, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: Is your desktop on the same network as your laptop? Are your friends on the same network as your laptop?

Comment: Yes, PC and Laptop are connected to the same network, laptop is with Wi-Fi, as desktop with cable. Friends are trying to connect via my **Public IP**.

Comment: I suppose `192.168.38.101` is the private ip address of your laptop that runs the server? If it is and it still doesn't work, how about port forwarding other ports that may have been used? [CS:GO Port Forward](https://portforward.com/counter-strike-global-offensive/)

Comment: Can you please move your desktop machine outside your local network, so that the desktop tries to connect your server from the Internet? This way you can test your port forwarding rules and when you manage to connect to your server, you know that your friends can too.